# ruby even Fibonacci numbers

Tags: arrays, ruby

I am a extreme newbie to coding, I am trying to find anything I can to practice on. This is one of the questions on the Euler test. This is what I came up with to get the answer, but I know it can be shortened. I am working with ruby. I have 2 questions.

1) what should I do to clean this up?
2) At the end I just had it pull the evens out and sum them. What I wanted to do was make an array of the numbers then search the array for the even answers then sum them. How can I make the result populate an array?

I know this is a simple thing that I am missing and I am sorry to bug you guys with such a newby thing.

```
1   bob=0
2   x = 0
3   y = 1
4   index = 0
5   while index < 4000000
6       z = (x+y)
7       x = y
8       y = z
9
10      index = y
11
12      if z.even?
13          bob = bob+z
14      end
15  end
16  p bob
```

Answer (score 2):

Create an array

```
array = []
```

Append elements to it

```
array << element
```

Filter it using `select`

```
array = array.select { |each| each.even? }
```

Sum all elements using `inject`

```
sum = array.inject { |a, b| a + b }
```

Best read the documentation of `Enumerable` module to learn about all of Ruby's array methods.

Some of the most useful functions are

- `all?`
- `any?`
- `collect`
- `each_cons`
- `each_slice`
- `detect`
- `inject`
- `none?`
- `select`
- `take`

Have fun with Euler project!

Comment: Ok I have tried the lines you wrote, and I can get a total, but how can I take the individual outputs of the equation and put it in an array as separate inputs, all I am able to do is take something like "z" in my program and put it in the array, but it gets overwritten as z increases each loop.

Comment: In your program use `bob = []` and then `bob << z`

Comment: Ok I was doing that but im an idiot, I put the array << z outside the loop so it only ever saw the end product.

Answer (score 0):

BTW, you can use methods chaining to simplify the code. Like this:

```
(1..10).select(&:even?).inject(:+)
```

`(1..10)` represents numbers range.
Take a look also at:

- [Select method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-select)
- [Inject method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject)

Answer (score 0):

This is probably best handled by an `Enumerator` [Docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerator.html). I would proceed as follows:

```
fib_only_evens = Enumerator.new do |y|
  a,b =0,1
  loop do
    y << a if a.even?
    a, b = b, a + b
  end
end
```

Then you can retrieve the number of even Fibonacci numbers that you want by using `Enumberable#first` or `#take`

```
fib_only_evens.first(10)
#=> [0, 2, 8, 34, 144, 610, 2584, 10946, 46368, 196418]  
fib_only_evens.take(20)
#=> [0, 2, 8, 34, 144, 610, 2584, 10946, 46368, 196418, 832040, 3524578, 
     14930352, 63245986, 267914296, 1134903170, 4807526976, 20365011074,
     86267571272, 365435296162]
```

Then using `Enumerable#reduce` to sum them

```
fib_only_evens.first(10).reduce(:+)
#=> 257114
```